# wrap input and select to inline in vm clarity UI

Tags: vmware-clarity

Hi I am trying vm clarity UI version 0.12.4, and I wanted to wrap input type date (clrDate) and input type select and there is no proper documentation on how to wrap, Can anyone please let me know how to wrap it to inline? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the "Layouts with grid" section [on this page of the Clarity forms documentation](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/forms).

Comment: Thanks Scott for your answer, I have followed this layouts with grid but my concern is i need to wrap clrDate component form datepicker which I have wrapped under clr-input-wrapper and clr-select is wrapped under clr-select-wrapper. I am little confused to wrap it inline.Thanks again.

Comment: <form class="clr-form clr-form-horizontal">
      <div class="clr-form-control clr-row">
        <label for="filter" class="clr-control-label clr-col-xs-12 clr-col-md-2 p7">FILTER BY : </label>
        <div class="clr-control-container clr-col-xs-12 clr-col-md-10">
          <div class="clr-input-wrapper">
            <input type="date" placeholder="From Date" size="10" clrDate><div class="clr-select-wrapper">
              <select id="select-basic" class="clr-select">
                <option value="" >Location</option></div></div></div>
            </form>